# Duplicate variable product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, duplicates

I want to create a script to create about a hundred of product with same characteristics but different name that are stored in a data base.

I'm currently using Woocommerce 3.1.1 and Wordpress 4.8.

When I use the class WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product and the function product_duplicate() with a simple product, it works fine. But when I want to duplicate a variable product, it returns me an error 500.

With some `var_dump`, it seems that the problem happen between the `return WC()->product_factory->get_product( $the_product, $deprecated );` in the wc_get_product() function and the `$duplicate = wc_get_product( $duplicate->get_id() );` in the product_duplicate() function.

**I call the function like this :**

```
$template = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
$wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product();
$alphonse_product = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( $template );’
```

Seeing `var_dumps`, it seems that `$template` is the correct product and is an instance of `WC_Product_Variable`.

**The logs are:**

> [Tue Jul 18 16:07:09.148186 2017] [core:error] [pid 27342] (36)File
>   name too long: [client ::1:33574] AH00036: access to
>   /mywebsite/wp-content/cache/minify/93868.js_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip failed (filesystem path
>   '/path/to/mywebsite/wp-content/cache/minify/93868.js_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip_gzip'),
>   referer: https://localhost/mywebsite/script-page/

Do you have any idea of what I could have done wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

`W3 Total Cache` was causing the problem.

Comment: Can you UPDATE your post with the error.log, please? It can be very importan to see the problem. So, add to the Woocommerce version because it changed in the version 3.x.

Comment: Ok some how, new logs were appearring from nowhere and show me that a cache plugin was active (surprisingly). After desactivating it, it seems to work fine... Sorry for the useless post...

Comment: But thank you for your answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that W3 Total Cache created this error. After deactivated it, it worked fine...

Comment: Ops, in these case I recommended turn off all cache (plugins, webserver,  cdn,  so on).